# Exit script with message

Tags: python

I am trying to exit my python script with my custom message but it displays this below error also

**Error:**

```
SystemExit: You have entered [n/N/No] as you dont want to play !!! 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2890: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

I want only to display this : `SystemExit: You have entered [n/N/No] as you dont want to play !!!`  and not `/usr/local  message`

**My code :**

```
status = 'y'
if status == 'y':
    print('Success')
else:
    sys.exit("You have entered [n/N/No] as you dont want to play !!!")
```

I am sing python : `Python 3.7.13`

Comment: The standard sys module's exit function doesn't do this in 3.10.4. Please show reproducible code and mention your Python version

Comment: @Lancelot du Lac  : please check the question I have updated python version